# nested if elif in view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code which is always returning an `HttpResponse` even if I change the URL to specify the format -

```
http://myserver/cdxcomposites/?format=xml
```

What am I doing wrong with my view?

```
@csrf_exempt
def cdxcomposites_list(request, format=None):
    """
    List all code, or create a new entry.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cdxcomposites = CDX_composites.objects.all()
        serializer = CDX_compositesSerializer(cdxcomposites, many=True)
        if format == 'csv':
            return CSVresponse(serializer.data)

        elif format == 'json':
            return JSONresponse(serializer.data)        

        elif format == 'xml':
            return XMLresponse(serializer.data)  

        elif format == 'yaml':
            return YAMLresponse(serializer.data)

        else:
            return HttpResponse(serializer.data)
```

I'm not including the POST as I haven't gotten that far yet.

edit -  if I'm reading correctly with my google-fu the problem is that my if and all my elif statements are not validating so I'm thinking the code is correct, I'm just missing out how to get the value into the view.  Here's my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('rds.views',
    url(r'^cdxcomposites/$', 'cdxcomposites_list'),
    url(r'^cdxcomposites/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 'cdxcomposites_detail'),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'xml', 'yaml', 'csv'])
```

Responding to comments seems the format isn't parsing.  I changed the last line to

```
return HttpResponse(format)
```

and it gives `None`.

Comment: Is `format` definitely being passed properly?

Comment: Try with the following url: `http://myserver/cdxcomposites/.xml`

Comment: @ 200-OK - that did it!  make it as an answer and I'll approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `format_suffix_patterns`, you need to pass the format type as `.xml` after the url:

```
http://myserver/cdxcomposites/.xml
```

Another option is to set the `Accept` header when sending the request.

Related docs: [Adding optional format suffixes to our URLs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls)

Answer (score 3):

Query parameters are never passed in via the view's argument list. That's for parts of the URL that are extracted in `urls.py`.

You need to be looking in `request.GET` for query parameters in the URL:

```
format = request.GET.get("format", None)
if format == 'csv':
    return CSVresponse(serializer.data)
#etc...
```

Comment: Isn't the `None` superfluous there? I'm assuming it's a normal dictionary `.get()`

Comment: Probably, but I included it for clarity. `request.GET` is a dictionary-like object, not a dictionary.